# Combination Sum IV Top-Down DP giving incorrect results

Tags: javascript, data-structures, ecmascript-6

Wrote a solution for Combination Sum IV using `Top-Down DP JavaScript solution` which is  giving incorrect results, any pointers what could have gone wrong

Here is **problem description**

```
            Input: nums = [1,2,3], target = 4
            Output: 7
            Explanation:
            The possible combination ways are:
            (1, 1, 1, 1)
            (1, 1, 2)
            (1, 2, 1)
            (1, 3)
            (2, 1, 1)
            (2, 2)
            (3, 1)
            Note that different sequences are counted as different combinations.
```

Here is the **solution in** `javascript`

```js
var combinationSum4 = function(N, T) {
  //w/ Top Down DP:
  // Create dp array
  const dp = Array(T + 1).fill(0)
  // Set default
  dp[0] = 1
  // Loop until we hit target
  for (let i = 1; i <= T; i++) {
    // Loop through all possible nums

    for (let j = 0; j < N.length; j++)

      if (N[j] <= i) {

        dp[i] += dp[i - N[j]]
      }
  }

  return dp[T]
};

let N = [1, 2, 3]

let T = 4

console.log(combinationSum4(N, T))
```

After adding console logs,output shows `52`

```
            var combinationSum4 = function(N, T) {
                //w/ Top Down DP:
                // Create dp array
                const dp = Array(T+1).fill(0)
                // Set default
                dp[0] = 1
                // Loop until we hit target
                for(let i = 1; i <= T;i++) {
                    // Loop through all possible nums
                    
                    for(let j = 0; j < N.length; j++)
                
                    if(N[j] <= i)
                        {
                           
                             dp[i] += dp[i- N[j]]
                             console.log(` i: ${JSON.stringify(i)}`)
                             console.log(`dp i: ${JSON.stringify(dp[i])}`)
                             console.log(`dp at dp[i- N[j]]:  ${JSON.stringify(dp[i- N[j]])}`)
                             console.log(`i- N[j]:  ${JSON.stringify(i- N[j])}`)
                             console.log(` N[j]:  ${JSON.stringify(N[j])}`)
                             console.log(` Actual code:  ${JSON.stringify(dp[i] += dp[i- N[j]])}`)
                        }
                    }

                return dp[T]
            };

            let N = [1,2,3]

            let T = 4

            console.log(combinationSum4(N,T))
```

Also how i can see all the `combinations in above code`

Output shown is `52` whereas expected is `7`
Your help is highly appreciated

Regards

Carolyn

Comment: The output appears to be 7 as desired

Comment: yeah when i add console logs ,it shows ```52``` ,any idea why it is happening, I just want to see detailed execution of code line by line